# Android - how to get frames from video file?

Tags: android, video, mediametadataretriever

I want to extract frames from video file stored on the device. Every solution i found is to use FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever or MediaMetadaraRetriever, but as I wrote [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60326306/extracting-frame-from-video-from-storage-device-using-mediametadataretriever-i) it's not working for me. Is there any other way to extract frames from video?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I admit I haven't used this method for a while, but if it still works with the current Android API, it should do the trick.

Please let me know if it still works. If not - I will delete this answer.

```
public static Bitmap getVideoFrame(Context context, Uri uri, long time) {

    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();

    try {

        retriever.setDataSource(context, uri);
        bitmap = retriever.getFrameAtTime(time);

    } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();

    } finally {

        try {

            retriever.release();

        } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return bitmap;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's not working for me, but it works when I use setDataSource(context, Uri) instead of setDataSource(path).